# Change font for text that has been google-prettified

Tags: css, angularjs, templates, fonts, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to change the default font of some text that I run through [google-code-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), inside an angular directive.

The template that my directive serves is like this.

```
<pre class= "prettyprint" style= "border:1px solid #98AFC7">
    My Text
</pre>
```

And the CSS that I am trying to use is like this.

```
pre.prettyprint{font-family:monospace; font-style: italic}
```

The font-style is there to assure myself that things are indeed hooked up correctly. "My Text" is in italics so I would say they are. However, the font-family is not being applied at all.

Would anyone know how to correctly specify the font for a template like this?

Answer (score 0):

prettyPrintOne, I have now found out, injects "span" tags into any text that you give it. I had to also specify the font for the "span" tags as well.